# SQL to LINQ Expression

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have specific SQL expression :

```
{
select * from courceMCPD.dbo.Contact c 
where c.cID in ( select cId from courceMCPD.dbo.Friend f where f.cId=5)
}
```

i would like to get LINQ expression that gets the same result.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like it's equivalent to something like:

```
var friendIds = from friend in db.Friends
                where friend.ContactId == 5
                select friend.ContactId;

var query = from contact in db.Contacts
            where friendIds.Contains(contact.Id)
            select contact;
```

(There are lots of different ways of representing the query, but that's the simplest one I could think of.)

It's pretty odd to perform a join on a particular field and *also* mandate that that field has to have a particular value though... there's not *very* much difference between that and:

```
var query = db.Contacts.Where(c => c.Id == 5);
```

... the only difference is whether there are any friend entries for that particular contact.

EDIT: Smudge gave another option for the query in a comment, so I'm promoting it into this answer...

```
var query = db.Contacts.Where(c => c.Friends.Any(f => f.cId == 5))
```

This assumes you've got an appropriate `Friends` relationship defined in the `Contacts` entity.

Comment: I agree with your points, just wondered if (sorry for code in comment) var query = db.Contacts.Where(c => c.Friends.Any(f => f.cId == 5)) works in C# (VB equiv does) and would it do what your last query did but also ensuring a friend exists?

Comment: @Smudge202: Yes, that should work fine, and is a nice and clean equivalent. It should give the same results as both queries, if a friend exists.

Answer (score 2):

Using labda expressions:

```
var query = dc.Contact
        .Where(c => dc.Friend.Select(f => f.cId).Contains(i.cID))
        .Where(c => c.cId == 5);
```

User "query" syntax:

```
var query = from c in dc.Contact
            where (from f in dc.Friend select f.cID).Contains(c.cId)
            where c.cId == 5
            select c;
```

Comment: You haven't included the "only contact 5" part.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified VB/C# so I'm going for VB =P

```
        Dim results As IEnumerable(Of yourEntities.Contact) = 
        (From c In yourContextInstance.Contacts Where (From f In yourContextInstance.Friends 
                                                       Where f.cId = 5 Select f.cId).Contains(c.cID))
```

Clearly, Jon's answer works, this query (I believe) just resembles your T-SQL Closer.

Comment: I've actually modified mine to be closer to yours, as there *is* a difference, if there are multiple Friend records. However, I've used a separate variable for the inner query, to make things clearer (IMO).

Comment: Fair one, though I think your last query can probably be adapted to be quite clean and encompass the whole functionality (albeit possibly less readable with the multiple lambdas).  No problem with you shifting your answer to be more in line with mine - quite an honour ;-)